# MariaDB grant privilege by using Wildcard host is not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using 5.5.35-MariaDB Server for the openstack keystone installation.

Below two commands are used to insert privileges for user keystone:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'keystone';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'keystone';
flush privileges;
```

But I met with the access deny issue when specify the hostname, which is written in the /etc/hosts file. While the access using 'localhost' is working fine.

```
[root@controller mariadb]# mysql -ukeystone -pkeystone -hcontroller
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'keystone'@'controller' (using password: YES)

[root@controller mariadb]# mysql -ukeystone -pkeystone -hlocalhost
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 98
Server version: 5.5.35-MariaDB MariaDB Server
```

The workaround for me is to grant privileges to host name explicitly, then it is working:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'controller' IDENTIFIED BY 'keystone';
```

Is that normal behavior, since above wildcard host ‘%’ is not working??

**UPDATE**

The query result is:

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'keystone';
+----------+-----------+
| User     | Host      |
+----------+-----------+
| keystone | %         |
| keystone | localhost |
+----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and the ip address and hostname is like:

```bsh
[root@controller rc]# ip address show Mgmt | grep inet
inet 10.0.10.101/24 brd 127.255.255.255 scope global Mgmt
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe9e:6e1a/64 scope link

[root@controller rc]# cat /etc/hosts | grep controller
10.0.10.101 controller
```

Comment: Please, show the result of the following query: `SELECT \`User\`, \`Host\` FROM \`mysql\`.\`user\` WHERE \`User\` = 'keystone';`

Comment: The query result is: MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE `User` = 'keystone';
+----------+-----------+
| User     | Host      |
+----------+-----------+
| keystone | %         |
| keystone | localhost |
+----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)  and the ip address and hostname is like: [root@controller rc]# ip address show Mgmt | grep inet
    inet 10.0.10.101/24 brd 127.255.255.255 scope global Mgmt
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe9e:6e1a/64 scope link
[root@controller rc]# cat /etc/hosts | grep controller
10.0.10.101 controller

Comment: The query result is: `MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'keystone'; +----------+-----------+ | User | Host | +----------+-----------+ | keystone | % | | keystone | localhost | +----------+-----------+ 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)` and the ip address and hostname is like: [root@controller rc]# `ip address show Mgmt | grep inet` inet 10.0.10.101/24 brd 127.255.255.255 scope global Mgmt inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe9e:6e1a/64 scope link [root@controller rc]# `cat /etc/hosts | grep controller` 10.0.10.101 controller

Comment: Ok, then check the following: [Configuring MariaDB for Remote Client Access](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/).

Answer (score 0):

User hostname explicitly instead of 'localhost'. It fixed the 1045 error.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'controller' IDENTIFIED BY 'keystone';